# Is there a way to query usage statistics in one go?

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

SQL flavor: **PostgreSQL**

Data table (tpm_data)
[image]

(Actual table uses JSONB fields and those have the **from**, **to** fields, however it is not relevant to the question)

Table represent a user usage of some kind (like a subscription). Example data:
[image]

I am trying to query usage statistics for a specific range of time and for a specific interval.

Example:

- **parameters:** from 2023-02-10 11:00 to 2023-02-10 18:00 and interval value: 1 hour
- **expected rows:**

| From | To | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-10 11:00 | 2023-02-10 12:00 | 0 |
| 2023-02-10 12:00 | 2023-02-10 13:00 | 4 min 45 s |
| 2023-02-10 13:00 | 2023-02-10 14:00 | 36 min 15 s |
| 2023-02-10 14:00 | 2023-02-10 15:00 | 51 min 23 s |
| 2023-02-10 15:00 | 2023-02-10 16:00 | 1 hour |
| 2023-02-10 16:00 | 2023-02-10 17:00 | 1 hour |
| 2023-02-10 17:00 | 2023-02-10 18:00 | 1 hour |

I am fiddling around with [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) and [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES)  however I am unable to produce a result which I want.

Comment: The actual table definition is not irrelevant, it is of the essence.

Comment: I've already solved the issue. 

And no, the full definition of a table is not relevant.
The essence of asking actions on Stackoverflow is simplifying the question and filtering out irrelevant data. That is precisely what I've done. 
Once I've created a query with this simplified structure a transition to a real table has been trivial.

Comment: Then you know more than I do. Limited as my knowledge is, I would have needed to know if these are `timestamp`s or `timestamp with time zone`, so that I could have chosen the appropriate version of `generate_series()`. I certainly didn't ask for clarification just to annoy you.